# Why the output in the following program comes as 12 bytes while total size is only 6 bits?

Tags: c++, structure, sizeof

The size of variable v comes as 12 bytes but since it's size is 6 bits , why it is not coming as 4 bytes ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct abc {
    int c : 4;
    char x : 1;
    int y : 1;
} v;

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof v; // it prints 12 . why?
}
```

Comment: To ensure everything is aligned properly in memory the struct will have its memory padded. It looks like your compiler is setting strides on a 4 byte boundary.  You have 2 ints which occupy 4 bytes each (an int32 but this is not explicitly defined, your compiler is resolving it to that), finally the char takes up 1 byte which would put you to 9 bytes. Memory cannot resolve on an odd number, each address must start at an even space, so it's padded with 3 bytes, therefore 4 + 4 + 4 = 12

Comment: you can see here:   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you mix the types for the bit-fields. That *could* cause the compiler to add padding to make sure the data is aligned. If you use `int` all over then no padding should be needed between members.

Note that this depends ***a lot*** on which compiler you are using. If I try it with GCC 6.2.0 on my home Linux system then I will get 4 bytes as size, no matter the types.

Comment: It also prints `4` on `OSX` using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0

Comment: Yes true, from `ISO C` std 1409 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. So there may or may not be padding.